# Why do they add a TRIAC after an MCP3020 optocoupler?

Tags: opto-isolator, triac, solid-state-relay

I have a relay circuit (I use it instead of a relay) that uses a [MCP3020](http://pdf.zener.ru/151914.pdf?datasheet%20Fairchild%20Optoelectronics%20Group%20MCP3022.300), which I think does the physical separation of the two circuits (it's a LED and a photo cell inside a chip) and a [BTA08 TRIAC](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/BTA08-600CW3-D.PDF).

Then connected to PIN 6 ("mains term") of the MCP3020 there is a resistor going to the middle pin (gate) of a BTA08 TRIAC. The other mains pin of the MCP3020 goes to the other mains pin of the TRIAC. It's like the MCP is switching (on/off) the voltage coming from mains to gate (plus the resistor). So, when the MCP3020 is on, then the TRIAC gate goes on and so the TRIAC allows AC through it's external pins. Isn't this redundant? What does the TRIAC do that the optocoupler does not do or vice-versa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason for adding a TRIAC with the opto-coupler is that **the TRIAC can handle much more current** (8 A RMS) than the opto-coupler (100 mA RMS). 80 times more current in this particular case.

Comment: If you just connected a 5v DC from a microcontroler and 220AC to the. other pins it would fry de microcontroller? So, triacs handle high current but don't isolate?

Comment: You can certainly drive a TRIAC with a microcontroller's output pin (I actually did that in a project, before I knew any better), but you must connect one of the microcontroller's power supply line (VCC or GND) to one of the mains' line. So you'll have your microcontroller connected to dangerous voltages. The opto-coupler provides the galvanic isolation between the logic level circuit and the mains voltage circuit.